# Repeated elements following an “and”: Use ’em or Lose ’em?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

Here is a sentence:

> You have to be nice to alleviate the social anxiety and start a healthy relationship.

Should it be like that or like this:

> You have to be nice to alleviate the social anxiety and **to** start a healthy relationship."

The first does not have a *to*, but the second does.  Which should I use, and why?  Or doesn’t it matter?

Comment: Either.  The first actually reads a hair smoother.

Comment: More like "Have a good reason to repeat'em."

Comment: ... or delete 'em.